# Bulk image rotation

Tags: images, media-library

I have just uploaded around 70 photos from Windows 10 into wordpress. While all of those photos in Windows are presented correctly Wordpress does not recognize their proper rotation. I may use wordpress media library to rotate each image one by one but this would take hours.

Do you know any plugin or way to insert fast rotate link into media library allowing rotation of multiple images at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a known problem between ios devices and Wordpress. It's a real issue due to the high numbers of iPhone/ipad users who also use Wordpress, and I'm surprised it hasn't been addressed in the Wordpress core. Looks like it's still being debated/ worked on [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14459).

It's a question that's been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777335/wordpress-doesnt-apply-rotation-to-iphone-images). As that answer notes, there are plugins for this job, including [ios images fixer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ios-images-fixer/) and [image rotation repair](https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-rotation-repair/) (not updated for a while) and [Image Rotation Fixer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-rotation-fixer/) although I'm not sure if they apply to existing images or only new uploads.

Comment: Sorry but I am using Windows 10 not IOS.

Comment: Where did the photos come from though?

Comment: Lumix camera, probably the issue is the same. I will try the plugins you mentioned.

Comment: Give them a go. I hope they work retrospectively, but I guess worse case is you just upload them again.

Comment: For sake of clearance: ios images fixer worked for me, while Image Rotation Fixer did not.

Comment: Good to hear. Thanks for the update @Abdel5

Answer (score 1):

Its the way the photos are encoded and they sometimes respond differently on different devices/platforms.

If the images aren't referenced in your posts, you can open them all in a program such as Adobe Bridge/Lightbox and bulk re-save them all. This should fix the issue, but is a bit more manual.